# Converting Signed Int to Unsigned String value in Java

Tags: java, binary, unsigned, signed, representation

To keep this short, I am getting a signed number, -25771 (in Java), that I need the unsigned String representation of, which is "4294941525".  Java thinks the number is signed two's complement, but I need its unsigned value.

I noticed the Javadoc for the toString() method for Integers only converts to signed representation.

Is there not a bitwise operation such as "& 0xFF" that I can do to get the unsigned number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would try

```
int val = -25771;
System.out.println(Long.toString(val & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
```

prints

```
4294941525
```

or

```
"" + (val & 0xFFFFFFFFL)
```

Comment: Those are both giving me 0 as the output, but the solution posted earlier by aix got a value that was close (the first half of the number was correct).

Comment: Can you give an example? You should only get 0, for 0.

Comment: I figured out the problem: I was using a currentDirectory.getInt(0x011A) method to read a TIFF metadata tag and your solution works now as long as I save the int into an actual int variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In Java 8, you can just use [`Integer.toUnsignedString(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedString-int-).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guava's [UnsignedInts.toString](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInts.html#toString%28int%29), and [parseUnsignedInt](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInts.html#parseUnsignedInt%28java.lang.String%29) to reverse the process.